# Is there a way to change the text of a actionbar menu item programatically and update in real time?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I have a fragment activity and swipe-able views and what not. So right now I just want to know... lets say if the user clicks on any of the items in the list then the menu item in the action bar will add 1.

In my action bar I have the item: "Count: " and another blank item that will store the amount of times a user clicks on an item (ID is countHolder)

So is there a way to have that countHolder update everytime the user clicks on an item and do it in real time?

Also how would it be achieveable? I know it would have to be in my onClickListener but I dont know how I would pass that variable around.

Answer (score 0):

From the click event you could try:

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Count: " + countHolder);
```

Comment: So I tried that and it's working kinda, but my action bar says "Cou.." and goes off screen? How can I fix that..?

Comment: Do you have any other items in your action bar that might be preventing the title from fully displaying?